# Returning ZERO with a specific precision using BigDecimal

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

I use the following code:

```
//...
else if(number.equals(ZERO))
    return BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(precision);
```

The function is invoked via

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(0);
System.out.println(Newton.sqrt(num, 5));
```

and always returns 0E-100 (regardless of the precision provided),  but I need 0.00000 etc.
Thanks

Comment: Note that `BigDecimal.ZERO` exists, you don't need to define your own constant for that.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that, but it does not solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Note also, that `BigDecimal.equals(Object)` will return `true` only *iff* the two instances' value *and* precision are the same. Try `BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal) == 0` instead. Although, I'm not sure what's the purpose of your code.

Comment: I want to return "0.0000000......" with a precision chosen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If your first piece of code if part of the `Newton.sqrt` method, then I take it for granted, that this return is not executed. You might take a look at the documentation of `BigDecimal.equals`.

What would work is this:

```
else if(number.signum() == 0)
    return BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(precision);
```

This of course works only if the method does not returnin some else `return` before that one and the `number` is really **exactly** zero (ignoring scale here). Since `Newton` hints at an approximation algorithm this most probably not the case. If this assumptions are true, then you must reconsider your requirements.

Comment: The problem is not that the "if" part fails, I have already verified that the code block is executed. The problem is that "0E-100" is the return value if I choose precision = 20 for example. I would expect  System.out.print(BigDecimal.ZEROsetScale(5)) to print "0.00000" instead of "0E-100"

Comment: @jgpt If I execute `System.out.println(BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(5));` then I get `0.00000`. Therefore I think I'm right unless you can provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example proving otherwise.

Comment: System.out.println(BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(50)); returns "0E-50" for me. The "0E-"-representation seems to start at precision = 7.

Comment: Then two things happened: First: Your example talks about "5" and "0E-100" - two numbers with do not match. Second: "0E-5" is the same _number_ as "0.0000", just the _representation_ of that number has changed (as chosen by `println`). If you want another representation then look at `java.text.DecimalFormat` to do your own format. But this is completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: Ok, thank you. "5" was just another example. That means if someone were to use me class, he would have to use java.text.DecimalFormat and it is not up to me to handle this problem when the function returns BigDecimal?

Comment: DecimalFormat is about converting a `BigDecimal` (or any `Number`) to a String (and vice versa). If you really want to return a `String` because you want a specific representation then you must go that way. __BUT__ in 99.99999% of all cases this is the wrong way when doing calculations. Therefore make it clear if you really want to muck with the representation of the number or with the number itself (i.e. its precision and/or scale).